# Ruby: Curious usage of "?" operator in comparing strings for equality

Tags: ruby

I found code similar to below in `ftp.rb` file.
I am wondering what is the use of `?` in the below example.  I know it is checking for equality, but never seen such a syntax

```
p "-" == ?-  # Prints true
p "a" == ?-  # Prints false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old syntax for one char strings.

`?-` means `'-'`

EDIT: turns out, I couldn't be more wrong. See @Jörg's comment below.

Comment: It's *not* syntax for a one-char string, it is syntax for the preferred character representation. In older versions, where the character representation (e.g. what is returned by `String#[]`) was a `Fixnum` representing the ASCII codepoint, a `?` literal evaluates to a `Fixnum`, on newer versions of Ruby, where the preferred character representation is a single-character `String`, it evaluates to a `String`. So, if you want to call it syntax for strings *at all*, you should call it *new* syntax for strings, not old syntax for strings, because on old versions, it is syntax for fixnums.